# Derivative of exponential function. What does this text mean?

Tags: derivatives

I am learning about derivatives of exponential functions and I came across this text:

[image]

I have a question about the highlighted text.

Is this because the value of $b^x$ at x=0 is 1 and so all that remains is the value of the limit?

Lastly, why does the proof treat $B^x$ as a constant? I guess the reason is that when calculating the limit when h -> 0, $b^x$ does not vary?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct on both those points.

Comment: That's being mean. In reality, the OP's problem is: it's the *definition* of the derivative at $x=0$, and they don't know nor care.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

regarding your second question.

If $f(x), g(x)$ are both continuous at $a.$

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)g(x) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x)\lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x)$

This might be worth proving, if you haven't done so already.

$\lim_\limits{h\to 0} b^x\frac {b^h - 1}{h} = \lim_\limits{h\to 0} b^x\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {b^h - 1}{h} = b^x\lim_\limits{h\to 0}\frac {b^h - b^0}{h}$

Comment: Is the limit of 2 products written correctly in your equation?